# Update table with is not null condition

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables in Access DB and I'm trying to update them with is not null condition and I am using this below query and it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE [Application]  INNER JOIN [Contacts] ON [Application].[Code] =  [Contacts].[Code] 
SET [Application].[Lead] =  [Contacts].[Lead]
where [Application].[Lead] IS NOT NULL
```

Is there any way to have is not null condition inside set and also I would need to update lot of column with same condition.

Really appreaciate any help on this.

Comment: Your query should work and there is no problem in that. Make sure you have correct column names and check for typo errors.

Comment: Can any `[Application].[Code]` have more than one `[Contacts].[Code]` match?